# how to give spectral data input as vector to 1D CNN (Convolution Nueral Network)

Tags: python, r, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, spectrum

1d CNN implementation for spectral data. how to give spectral data input as vector to CNN
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]